# How to Implement a Data Model in C# and Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: database, xamarin, sqlite, visual-studio-mac

I'm coming from the world of Xcode where working with SQLite is not necessary since they provide CoreData to make it easier to deal with Entities and Attributes. So in my try to create a data model without using the GUI for doing that I'm lost.

The following picture shows what I want to do:

[image: Core Data from Xcode]

And this is the code where I'm lost.

```
using System;
using SQLite;

namespace NameAnimalPlants
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        #region Computed Propoperties

        // I want this separated 
        public string ANameTextField { get; set; } = "";
        public string BNameTextField { get; set; } = "";
        public string CNameTextField { get; set; } = "";

        // I want this separated
        public string AAnimalTextField { get; set; } = "";
        public string BAnimalTextField { get; set; } = "";
        public string CAnimalTextField { get; set; } = "";

        // I want this separated
        public string APlantTextField { get; set; } = "";
        public string BPlantTextField { get; set; } = "";
        public string CPlantTextField { get; set; } = "";

        public SQLiteConnection Conn { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public DataModel()
        {
        }

        // How should I implement this method?
        public DataModel (string firstRow, string secondRow, string thirdRow)
        {
            this.ANameTextField = firstRow;
            this.BNameTextField = secondRow;
            this.CNameTextField = thirdRow;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

How to separate each entity in my data model? How should I implement each method properly? Any help or tutorial related to the example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Entity of your Core Data model:

[image]

Becomes a C# class:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string aAnimal { get; set; }
    public string bAnimal { get; set; }
    public string cAnimal { get; set; }
}
```

> How should I implement this method?

You can add a specialized constructor to initialize your object:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal() { }

    public Animal(string aAnimal, string bAnimal, string cAnimal)
    {
        this.aAnimal = aAnimal;
        this.bAnimal = bAnimal;
        this.cAnimal = cAnimal;
    }

    public string aAnimal { get; set; }
    public string bAnimal { get; set; }
    public string cAnimal { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection("coredata.sqlite");
conn.CreateTable<Animal>();
var aNewAnimal = new Animal("Stack", "Over", "Flow");
conn.Insert(aNewAnimal);

var retrivedAnimal = conn.Table<Animal>().First();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. After I created three different object models (Animal, Name and Plant) how can I connect each one in the database? Can you be more specific on the "Usage" section? Where is the right place in my application to add the specific code? should I create a specific connection with the database in each object model class

Comment: @FotiosTragopoulos A novel could be written about your questions, well maybe a short story ;-) One right off the top: `should I create a specific connection with the database in each object model class`? No, there can be exceptions, but normally you hold a single connection to the database that is shared among the entire data model (via a singleton, a factory pattern, etc.. ). Xamarin has a macOS w/Sqlite sample app that you should review and if you have specific questions, post another question so the community can review and help... https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mac/MacDatabase/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the context of your question it sounds like you're writing a Xamarin mobile app, so I'll answer under that assumption.  Also, it's not clear from your question as to what exactly you want to do with the data or how your data entities should relate to each other, but I'll try to give some pointers that might help give you some direction.

The first thing I would do is separate the data model itself from the thing that stores that data.  So you'd have two classes - DataModel which holds the data, and DataService which is responsible for the [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations to your database.  It might look something like this when you've separated them.

Here's the data model:

```
using System;

namespace NameAnimalPlants
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string ANameTextField { get; set; };
        public string BNameTextField { get; set; };
        public string CNameTextField { get; set; };

        public string AAnimalTextField { get; set; };
        public string BAnimalTextField { get; set; };
        public string CAnimalTextField { get; set; };

        public string APlantTextField { get; set; };
        public string BPlantTextField { get; set; };
        public string CPlantTextField { get; set; };

        public DataModel (string aNameTextField, string bNameTextField, string 
cNameTextField, string aAnimalTextField, string bAnimalTextField, string cAnimalTextField, string aPlantTextField, string bPlantTextField, string cPlantTextField)
        {
            this.ANameTextField = aNameTextField;
            this.BNameTextField = bNameTextField;
            this.CNameTextField = cNameTextField;
            this.AAnimalTextField = aAnimalTextField;
            this.BAnimalTextField = bAnimalTextField;
            this.CAnimalTextField = cAnimalTextField;
            this.APlantTextField = aPlantTextField;
            this.BPlantTextField = bPlantTextField;
            this.CPlantTextField = cPlantTextField;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the data service:

```
using System;
using SQLite;

namespace NameAnimalPlants
{
    private SQLiteConnection _conn;

    public class DataService
    {
        public DataService (SQLiteConnection _conn)
        {
            _conn = conn;
        }

        public DataModel GetByNameText(string nameText)
        {
            //This is just an example of the type of function you would put in your data service.  You can add whatever functions you need to support the types of queries you need. 

            //Add some code here to query SQLite tables by nameText
        }

        public bool Save(DataModel dataModelObject)
        {
            //This is just an example of the type of function you would put in your data service.  You can add whatever functions you need to support saving a data model object to your database.  You may want a single Save method that knows how to determine if it is a UPDATE or an INSERT, or you may want to separate that out into two functions. 

            //Add some code here to update/insert the dataModelObject to the SQLite tables, and then return a bool (or some other sort of result object) indicating the success of that save.
        }

        public bool Delete(DataModel dataModelObject)
        {
            //Add some code here to delete the dataModelObject from the SQLite tables, and then return a bool (or some other sort of result object) indicating the success of that delete.
        }
    }
}
```

And, here's how you would use them in your app, to save an object for example:

```
DataModel myDataModelObject = new DataModel("Some aNameTextField text", "Some bNameTextField text", "Some cNameTextField text", "Some aAnimalTextField text", "Some bAnimalTextField text", "Some cAnimalTextField text", "Some aPlantTextField text", "Some bPlantTextField text", "Some cPlantTextField text");

DataService myDataService = new DataService(new SQLiteConnection("some connection string"));

myDataService.Save(myDataModelObject);
```

If you find that you don't like working with SQLite, you may want to consider a NoSQL option for storing your data on the mobile device, like Realm.  It's super easy to work with and you can simply store your DataModel objects as is.  If you do that then all you have to do is install the Realm Nuget packages into your mobile projects.  You'll need to do this for each of your Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and PCL projects (if you're using Xamarin.Forms).  Then all you have to do is have your DataModel derive from RealmObject like this...

```
namespace NameAnimalPlants
{
    public class DataModel : RealmObject
    {
        //Everything else in this class - properties, constructors, etc. - stays exactly the same as before.
    }
}
```

And then in your DataService you would remove the SQLite references and add a Realm reference, and your Save method would look as simple as this:

```
public bool Save(DataModel dataModelObject)
{
    try
    {
        Realm db = Realm.GetInstance();
        db.Write(() =>
        {
            db.Add(newEntry);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }        
    return true;
}
```

I would recommend at least looking into Realm before you get too far down the SQLite road.  You can get more info here:

[Realm Mobile Database](https://realm.io/docs/)

Comment: The application is for OS X. It's a sample project so I can find out how VS for Mac with C# and SQLite works. Thanks for letting me now about Realm I read the overview and it looks really interesting but it works only on mobile apps.